# Random expanding circles in canvas Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

i am new here, and i am new to coding. Currently doing a game project. Until now my code makes random circles which the user has to click to make disappear. I want to make it so that once the circle appears it starts expanding and after a certain point it will reverse till the circle is gone. The user has to click the circle before is disappears. Within the randomize function i tried to use some if statements, but it did not work. The circles only expand once you click one of the already drawn circles. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
      <style type="text/css">
      #canvas{
              display:inline;
              margins:auto;}
      </style>


    <canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="700" ></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    var circles = [];
    function drawCanvas() {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (var a = 0; a < circles.length; a++) {
            drawCircle(circles[a].x, circles[a].y, circles[a].r);
        }
    }
    function drawCircle(x, y, radius){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();
    }
    function clickCircle(xmus, ymus){
        for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {            
            var distance = Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(xmus - circles[i].x, 2)
                + 
                Math.pow(ymus - circles[i].y, 2)
            );
           console.log(distance);
           if(distance < circles[i].r){   
               //Remove the circle from our array
                circles.splice(i, 1); //This removes 1 element from our circles array at index i
               //Then redraw our canvas from the beginning
               drawCanvas();
            }
        }
    }
    
    canvas.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
        const y = event.clientY - rect.top;
        clickCircle(x,y);
    });
    
    function randomize(){
        var radius = Math.floor(Math.random()*25)+10;

        for (var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++){  
        if(circles[j].r < 50){
            circles[j].r += 2;}

        else if (circles[j].r == 50 || circles[j].r > 50){
            circles[j].r -= 2;
        }}
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600)+50;
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+50;
        circles.push({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            r: radius
        });
        drawCircle(x,y,radius);
    }
    
    var interval = setInterval(randomize, 1000);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The canvas is only ever being redrawn on click or once a second.

Comment: To make your code easier to maintain, recommend you remove the if/else from the randomize and place it into it's own function (like `resize()`). Once you do that, call `resize()` inside randomize and add `drawCanvas()` at the end of the `resize()` function. But, I think you'll find a flaw in your logic. Each iteration will have them grow or shrink to a certain size, and then shrink or grow over and over. Without ever disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `randomize` function only draws the newest circle, not any of the other circles. Replace `drawCircle(x,y,radius)` with `drawCanvas()` to redraw all the earlier circles on each cycle too.
2. As pointed out in a comment, your `if` condition expands the circle to radius 50, then will shrink it back to 48 in the next cycle, so that they all get stuck alternating between 48 and 50. Change your logic, for example by letting each circle have a `growth` property that becomes negative when the radius reaches 50.
3. You currently have nothing to remove the circles whose radius is reached zero.
4. You shouldn't `splice` an array in the middle of a loop over that array - it will change the indices and skip some of the circles. Instead, use `filter` to remove the unwanted ones.

Your `randomize` function would then be rewritten like this:

```
function randomize(){
        var radius = Math.floor(Math.random()*25)+10;

        for (var j = 0; j < circles.length; j++){  
            circles[j].r += circles[j].growth;
            if (circles[j].r > 50 && circles[j].growth > 0) {
                circles[j].growth = -circles[j].growth;
            } 
        }

        // keep only those that still have positive radius:
        circles = circles.filter(circle => circle.r > 0);

        var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*600)+50;
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+50;
        circles.push({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            r: radius,
            growth: +2
        });
        drawCanvas();
    }
```

For more advanced games, you may want to have a separate timer using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to update the canvas, by adding something like this to the end of your code:

```
function step() {
    drawCanvas();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
step();
```

This saves having to call `drawCanvas` every time you change anything in the screen. The canvas will be redrawn automatically when the display refreshes.